# Catch request to a file in content folder to handle with controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I got a third party widget library I have to use. This library has a hardcoded string to a file. Is it possible to intercept this request with routes? My try looked like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "ribbonbar",
                url: "Content/Ribbon/Scripts/Ribbon.Tabs.foo",
                defaults: new { controller = "Ribbon", action = "Index" });
```

But I only got a 404. Is it impossible or do I have mixed something up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You will need to add the following handler to your web.config in order to ensure that this request goes through the managed pipeline and your routes:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        ...
        <add 
            name="MyCustomhandler" 
            path="Content/Ribbon/Scripts/Ribbon.Tabs.foo" 
            verb="GET" 
            type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
            preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

and then you could have the following controller action to serve this request:

```
public class RibbonController
{
    // GET Content/Ribbon/Scripts/Ribbon.Tabs.foo
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var file = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/foo.bar");
        return File(file, "application/foo-bar");
    }
}
```

You could also serve all requests to `Content/Ribbon/Scripts/*` from the same controller action:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        ...
        <add 
            name="MyCustomhandler" 
            path="Content/Ribbon/Scripts/*" 
            verb="GET" 
            type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
            preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

and a route like that:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ribbonbar",
    url: "Content/Ribbon/Scripts/{name}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Ribbon", action = "Index" }
);
```

with an action like that:

```
public class RibbonController
{
    // GET Content/Ribbon/Scripts/*
    public ActionResult Index(string name)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively to using a specific handler you could have enabled managed modules for all requests like that:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    ...
</system.webServer>
```

But I wouldn't recommend you enabling this option because now all requests will go through the managed pipeline, even those from for static resources which might have a negative impact on the performance of your application. It's much better to selectively enable this only for selected urls.

Comment: thank you for your elaborated answer. Is it possible to access the GET Parameter that might be appended to the request. For example http://localhost/Content/Ribbonbar/Scripts/Ribbonbar.Tabs.foo?tabs=home,insert,page-layout,references,mailings. The RouteData.Values dictionary does not contain them.